# Querying CSV file with LibreOffice database

Tags: database, csv, libreoffice

I am trying to do some simple sql operations against a csv file.

To get it to run I am creating a new LibreOffice *text* database over a folder containing all my csv files.  But my tests are failing.

With this sample file:

### Customers.csv

```
Customer,Date,Quantity,Price
"John Doe",15/01/2012,12,20
"Doe John",15/01/2012,2,25
"John Doe",20/01/2012,1,23
```

And this query:

### Query

```
SELECT "Customer", COUNT(*) AS numero FROM "Customers" GROUP BY "Customer"
```

It doesn't show me any result (it's empty) on column 'numero'.  And it is not doing the GROUP BY neither.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be a "text db" restriction / bug; you may be better off by [importing the csv data into a standard LibreOffice database (hsqldb)](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=23260).

Comment: @tohuwawohu The main argument to use a "text db" is *not* create any table.  The how-to you are provided needs to do a CREATE TABLE at first.  Thanks anyway.